# Efeito em navbar bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-3

Pessoal gostaria de saber como é que eu faço essa animação do cabeçalho desse site https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/ o efeito de quando eu desço a página o cabeçalho muda de tamanho e cor? Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, agradeço desde já!

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há diversos métodos, você pode utilizar uma função que ao rolar a página adicione uma classe ao fundo que estava transparente, nessa classe você pode inserir um transition no CSS para dar este efeito.

Segue o Javascript para isto:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        $timeout(function() {
            if(top > 0){
                $(".menu_fixo").addClass('fundo_preto');
            }else{
                $(".menu_fixo").removeClass('fundo_preto');
            }
        });
    });
```

Neste fundo preto, adicione o css:

```
transition: all 0.2s ease;
background-color: #000;
```

Para a Logo se mexer para o lado, adicione uma classe também e nessa classe de padding e transition para esse padding.

Segue resposta em pergunta semelhante: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765155/shrinking-navigation-bar-when-scrolling-down-bootstrap3